# What's wrong with this proof that the sample sum is sufficient for $\theta$ in $U(0,\theta)$?

Tags: uniform-distribution, sufficient-statistics, rao-blackwell

So let's say $X_i ~ U(0, \theta)$, and let's consider the two-sample sample sum, $t = \bar{X_2} = (X_1 + X_2)/2$.

So we want to show that $p(x|t) = p(x,t)/p(t) = p(x)/p(t)$ is independent of $\theta$. So we know that $p(x) = \frac{1}{\theta^2}$.

Then, let's find the distribution of $X_1 + X_2$. With a bit of algebra, we get that $p_{X_1 + X_2}(x) = \frac{x I(0<x<\theta) + (-x + 2\theta)I(\theta<x<2\theta)}{\theta^2}$.

So then $\frac{p(x)}{p(t)} = \frac{1}{x}$ on $0<x<\theta$, and $\frac{p(x)}{p(t)} = \frac{0}{-x + 2\theta} = 0$ on $\theta<x<2\theta$, so the sample sum is sufficient for t.

Is the issue just that this argument doesn't generalize to more than two samples? If so, how would I show that?

Thanks.

Comment: Hint: $t$ is not sufficient!

Comment: You're trying to show that $p(x)/p(t)$ is independent of $\theta$, but there's a $\theta$ in your expression for $p(x)/p(t)$, so what you've demonstrated is that $t$ is not sufficient.

Comment: @jbowman but since the numerator on $ 0 < x < 2\theta$ is zero, doesn't that mean that overall the pdf is independent of $\theta$?

Comment: OH, my mistake. I see. The point at which we transition from one piecewise part to the other depends on $\theta$, which is the problem, despite the individual pieces not. Thanks.

Comment: And you also have $2\theta-x$ in the denominator of your second expression, but you're right too.

Comment: @user49404: Now that you find your error, you can self-answer so this does not linger on ...